# any nginx API to write my log to access_log?

Tags: nginx

I install a http module so that my postinitialize function will be called once configuration is loaded. I want to write something in the function to access_log file so that the data can be processed with access log data together.

Does nginx provide API to write something to the access log file ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#logging